# Streaming Camera between two android phones without Internet

Tags: camera, wifi-hotspot, streaming

Is it possible to stream live camera from one android phone to other without Internet using wifi-hotspot of one these phones?
I have tried IP webcam app. But the other mobile's browser can't connect to given ip address (with x.x.x.x refused to connect error) . Second phone is connected to wifi-hotspot created by the first one.

Are there any other app available that can stream camera with wifi-hotspot connectivity?